# NuGet package, define common minumum version, allow higher?

Tags: visual-studio, package, nuget, version

I want to centrally specify minimum NuGet package versions, to exclude vulnerable, transitive dependencies, but also allow later versions, if required as transitive dependencies by other packages.

I am trying the rather new Central Package Management (CPM) in Visual Studio 2022, using a *Directory.Packages.props* file on solution level:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/dependency-resolution
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/introducing-central-package-management/

Alternatively, I could use *Directory.Build.props* or the older *packages.config*.

**In *packages.config* it would look like:**

`<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="13.0.1" allowedVersions="13.0.0" />`

with the *allowedVersions="13.0.0"* allowing everything *13.0.0* or greater.

**Behavior, for NuGet packages referenced in projects, should be:**

1. Package *JsonA* has transitive *Newtonsoft.Json 12.0.1* => gets *13.0.1*
2. Project requires *Newtonsoft.Json 13.0.3* (update, new version in project)
3. Package *JsonB* requires transitive *Newtonsoft.Json 13.0.3* => project shall get update to *13.0.3*

**Case 3 fails when I define**

`<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />`

in one of the *Directory.x.props* files, I get *NU1605 Detected Package Downgrade* error (or warning, depending on error config).
But package *JsonB* (case 3) shall be using version *13.0.3*, without specifying the transitive dependency in the project explicitly.

**Is this possible, and if, how?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found it, as far as the minimum version, using Central Package Management CPM, as linked above (VS2022 17.2+, NuGet 6.2+).

For *Newtonsoft.Json*, it looks like this.
In the *Directory.Packages.props* file (new with CPM):

```xml
    <PropertyGroup>
        <ManagePackageVersionsCentrally>true</ManagePackageVersionsCentrally>
        <CentralPackageTransitivePinningEnabled>true</CentralPackageTransitivePinningEnabled>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

*TransitivePinning* makes NuGet pull the declared version for transitive dependencies, even if they declare another version.

Then the *PackageVersion* element. This **only** specifies the version, does **not** add the package to all projects. Actually, a *PackageVersion* declaration may not be used at all.

`<PackageVersion Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />`

In the project file, without *Version* attribute:

`<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" />`

Other versions can be referenced on project level via *VersionOverride* attribute.

An automatic upgrade to later versions, e.g. when a dependency requires *Newtonsoft.Json 13.0.4*, does **not** work yet and has to be edited manually. *PackageVersion* *Version* attributes may, as of now, not contain floating versions (* wildcard, range notation).

**Difference to old *Directory.Build.props*:**

That one had only the *PackageReference* element; adding one on solution level would create a dependency in every NuGet package created by the solution, even where not needed.

Comment: Yes, you can automatically override a transitive package version by enabling transitive pinning. If possible, you could Accept your own answer ,it could help other community members who get the same issues issue to find the solution easily.

Comment: It's a shame that the version attribute doesn't seem to honour the nuget version specification. I've tried to set [`13.0.1,)` but it treats it as 13.0.1 and you still get the version conflict warning when a package wants a later version.